# How do I update a SQlite DB list with a new value?

Tags: database, sqlite, variables, updating

I'm trying to update a list in a SQLite DB after recalling the stock value and reducing it by one?

Here is the code I have used:

```
ComicID = int(input("Enter Comic ID: "))
    with sqlite3.connect("Chris_comics.db") as db:
        if ComicID == 111:
            cursor.execute("""select Value from Comics where ComicID=?""",(ComicID,))
            result1=cursor.fetchone()
            result1= repr(result1).replace(',','').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            print(result1)
            Grandtotal = Grandtotal + int(result1)
            cursor.execute("""select Stock from Comics where ComicID=?""",(ComicID,))
            StockUpdate = cursor.fetchone()
            StockUpdate = repr(StockUpdate).replace(',','').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            StockUpdate = int(StockUpdate) - 1
            print(StockUpdate)
            ##check cursor.execute for updating stock
            cursor.execute = "update Comics set Stock={0} where ComicID=?" .format(StockUpdate)
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) says:

> **commit()**
>   This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to `commit()` is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Comment: So I need to add `commit()` after the last line of code?